# Caret symbol getting ignored when calling a sybase stored procedure through batch file

Tags: batch-file, stored-procedures, sybase

I am calling a Sybase Stored proc from a batch file. One of the parameters of the SP is a search pattern. When I pass a search pattern of `'a-zA-Z0-9_/.+-^^*'`  , the search pattern reaching the SP is `''a-zA-Z0-9_/.+-^*'` . One carat at the end is missing. This I came to know since I am unloading the contents of all the SP parameters to a *.txt* file.

```
'SET searchpattern=
if [%5]==[] (
SET searchpattern='a-zA-Z0-9_/.+-^^*'
) ELSE ('



Call SP XYZ like-
EXEC XYZ(%searchpattern%)
```

Can someone please tell me how to ensure that whatever pattern is in the batch file goes to the SP unaltered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Carot is the escape character.  For each carot, use two carots so that it escapes itself.

```
echo ^&
echo ^>
echo ^^
```

Double quoting the term is another option, if you can use that.